# Problem with declaring and changing the value of a variable in julia

Tags: julia

What is wrong with my code? Do I have to declare `x` before using it?

```
function f(n::Int64, t::Int64)
A = ones(n,n)
for i=0:t
    if i > 0
        A[x,a] = rand()*A[x,a] + rand()
    end
    y = rand(1:n)
    b = rand(1:n)
    if i > 0
        A[x,a] = rand()*A[x,a] + rand()*A[y,b]
    end
    x = y
    a = min(b, rand(1:n))
end
return A
end
```

Here is the error thrown when trying to call `f`:

> UndefVarError: x not defined

Comment: You have to initialise it

Comment: The first time the code is run what is the address of A[x,a]? It comes up as A[undef,undef] so what is the computer suppose to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason is more complex, as similar code in Python would work.

For example compare (Python):

```
>>> def f():
...     for i in range(3):
...         if i > 0:
...             print(a)
...         a = i
...
>>> f()
0
1
```

to (Julia):

```
julia> function f()
           for i in 0:2
               if i > 0
                   println(a)
               end
               a = i
           end
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f()
ERROR: UndefVarError: a not defined
```

So what is the difference? As the Julia manual explains [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/#For-Loops-and-Comprehensions-1) you have:

> `for` loops, `while` loops, and comprehensions have the following behavior: any new variables introduced in their body scopes are freshly allocated for each loop iteration, as if the loop body were surrounded by a `let` block

This means that in your code variables `a` and `x` as they are local to the `for` loop are freshly allocated in each iteration of the loop. Because of this the variable has to be assigned to **before** it is accessed **inside the loop**.

Therefore it is not needed to **assign a value to `x` and `a`** before the loop. It is enough to define them in scope outer to the loop (even without assigning of the value). For example like this:

```
julia> function f(n::Int64, t::Int64)
           A = ones(n,n)
           local x, a
           for i=0:t
               if i > 0
                   A[x,a] = rand()*A[x,a] + rand()
               end
               y = rand(1:n)
               b = rand(1:n)
               if i > 0
                   A[x,a] = rand()*A[x,a] + rand()*A[y,b]
               end
               x = y
               a = min(b, rand(1:n))
           end
           return A
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1,1)
1×1 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.94526289614139
```

Now it works because `x` and `a` are not freshly allocated in each iteration of the loop.

In my original toy example it would look like:

```
julia> function f()
           local a
           for i in 0:2
               if i > 0
                   println(a)
               end
               a = i
           end
       end
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f()
0
1
```

and you see that you get exactly what you had in Python.